# Trouble accessing USB device using libusb library: (Error opening device)

Tags: c, mingw, device, libusb-1.0

I am working on a project that involves fetching input data from a gaming controller using the libusb library. However, I am encountering an issue where the program fails with the message "Error opening device." I have tried several troubleshooting steps, but the problem persists.

**Problem Description:**
I wrote the following code to open the USB device:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libusb-1.0.26/libusb-1.0.26/libusb/libusb.h"

#define VENDOR_ID 0x045E  // Replace with your controller's vendor ID
#define PRODUCT_ID 0x028E // Replace with your controller's product ID
#define FILENAME "controller_data.txt"

int main() {
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle;
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL;

    // Initialize libusb
    if (libusb_init(&ctx) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing libusb\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the device with the specified vendor and product IDs
    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
    if (dev_handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening device\n");
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        return 1;
    }

    // Claim the interface (assuming interface 0)
    if (libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error claiming interface\n");
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file\n");
        libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0);
        libusb_close(dev_handle);
        libusb_exit(ctx);
        return 1;
    }

    // Read data from the controller, print to console, and write to file
    unsigned char data[64];
    int transferred;

    while (1) {
        int result = libusb_interrupt_transfer(dev_handle, 0x81, data, sizeof(data), &transferred, 0);
        if (result == 0) {
            // Process and print data to console
            for (int i = 0; i < transferred; ++i) {
                printf("%02X ", data[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            // Write data to file
            fwrite(data, 1, transferred, file);
            fflush(file);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading data: %d\n", result);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Release the interface, close the device, and close the file
    libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0);
    libusb_close(dev_handle);
    fclose(file);

    // Deinitialize libusb
    libusb_exit(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

i triple checked my device ids which i found to be correct and also tried changing usb ports.

Comment: Are you not running a window manager?  How do you prevent X or Wayland from claiming the device?

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot that you wanna help. Actualy i'm working in windows-11 MSYS2 MINGW32 terminal with mingw and gcc installed for the programming, compiling and to run, and i opened steam to test the controller connection once(which seemed to work properly) and then closed steam from task manager, so there's no chance steam or any other application connecting to my device or is there any process to check if your doubt is right?